# Class names joined by a + sign

Tags: objective-c

I apologize if this is rudimentary, but I can't seem to find the explanation I am looking for due to not knowing correctly what to call it.

What is it called when you create a new class whose file name is a class that already exists, followed by a + sign, followed by some another name. **[Existing Class]+[New Class].m**

i.e. NSString+CSSizing.m

```
// NSString+CSSizing.h
@interface NSString (CSSizing)

// NSString+CSSizing.m
@implementation NSString (CSSizing)
```

I understand that they basically add additional methods to the base class, but I don't know what this is called exactly. Also, is it possible to create an instance of CSSizing using the above example?

Comment: "Also, is it possible to create an instance of CSSizing using the above example?" No.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are [categories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html). The "Class+Thing" is just a naming convention for categories to make it clear which class the category is on and what the category adds.

Comment: Yes, and not to be confused with extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You would not create an instance of the category, but by importing the category's .h file into another implementation file, you gain access to the methods added by that category.  In other words, you create an instance of an NSString and can then call methods in the CSSizing category on it.

For more, look here: [Customizing Existing Classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)